# How to pass functions as arguments TO a lambda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, callback

I am trying to use a lambda as a way to handle both rising/falling states of a GPIO button. So I pass a callback for falling (c1) and rising (c2) to create a lambda that will later be used when a GPIO button is pressed. But it doesn't work:

```
# Create lambda to handle both rising and falling triggers/callbacks
def trigger_both( self, pin, c1, c2):
    return lambda pin, c1, c2: c1() if GPIO.input(pin) else c2()
```

Both c1 and c2 are functions. Error at runtime when the lambda is executed:

TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'c1' and 'c2'
TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'c1' and 'c2'

In context:

```
    if callback and callback2:
        callback_both = self.trigger_both(pin, callback, callback2)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(pin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=callback_both, bouncetime=200)
```

Comment: You'll have to come up with another design. The `callback` function passed to `add_event_detect` is being called with only the `channel` (pin) argument

Comment: Yes, true, but I don't need/want to have c1/c2 called at runtime - this was my coding error. The accepted answer fixed it: `return lambda pin: c1(pin) if GPIO.input(pin) else c2(pin)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `callback_both()` is passed the single argument `pin`, we might get away with a simple *closure*:

```
def trigger_both(self, c1, c2):
    return lambda pin: c1(pin) if GPIO.input(pin) else c2(pin)
```

If not, consider the longer form:

```
def trigger_both(self, c1, c2):
    return lambda pin, f1=c1, f2=c2: f1(pin) if GPIO.input(pin) else f2(pin)
```

No need to pass `pin` to `trigger_both()` if it's passed by the event handler.  I'm just passing `pin` to `c1()` and `c2()` for completeness -- you can remove or ignore it.  We can probably also do this with `partial` instead of `lambda`:

```
from functools import partial

def trigger_both(self, c1, c2):
    def callback_both(f1, f2, pin):
        return f1(pin) if GPIO.input(pin) else f2(pin)

    return partial(callback_both, c1, c2)
```

Or, again, a simpler closure:

```
def trigger_both(self, c1, c2):
    def callback_both(pin):
        return c1(pin) if GPIO.input(pin) else c2(pin)

    return callback_both
```